# Setting ListBox ItemsSource to an object from StaticResource as shown in MSDN

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource, staticresource

I was exploring `DataTemplate` and found [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_datatemplates) on MSDN. It says -

"*In this sample application, there is a ListBox control that is bound to a list of photos:*

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPhotos}}"
     Background="Silver" Width="600" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

*This ListBox currently looks like the following:*"

[image]

//...some stuff about `DataTemplate`...//

*In our sample application, each custom `Photo` object has a `Source` property of type string that specifies the file path of the image. Currently, the photo objects appear as file paths.*"

"*For the photos to appear as images, you create a DataTemplate as a resource:*"

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<!--DataTemplate to display Photos as images
    instead of text strings of Paths-->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Photo}">
  <Border Margin="3">
    <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
...
</Window.Resources>
```

OK, fair enough, so I declared the Photo class -

```
public class Photo
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML sense is not very good (it's *bad* actually). What I don't get here is the way *ItemsSource* of the ListBox is set. As far as my XAML goes, "MyPhotos" here have to be an `x:Key` to an *IEnumerable* object of Photo type, something like -

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<local:PhotoList x:Key="MyPhotos"/>
...
</Window.Resources>
```

But I don't have any idea how the *PhotoList* class should look like in this case. So, what the *Resource* would actually look like that cause the ListBox to be populated with the `Source` strings of the photos?

**FYI :** Implementing things in my own way, my `DataTemplate` exploration got successful, and though this thing here was not my primary concern, I just want to know what I don't know. Can anyone shed some light?

**EDIT in response to the Answer provided by** [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b)**:**

The point of the question is to get the result, as shown in the image, before applying the DataTemplate and to get an idea of the Resource that make that happen.

If I make the `PhotoList` itself an *IEnumerable*, like -

```
public class PhotoList : List<Photo>
{
    //some property to hold the collection of Photo objects??
}
```

and instantiate it within the Resource, then *to* what the `ItemsSource` actually gets bound? How it's gonna work? Sorry I didn't understand. I hope you'll elaborate a bit more on this.

So, I went for the `DataSourceProvider` option. But since the `Data` property has no setter, I tried the following -

```
public class Photo
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoList : DataSourceProvider
{
    private List<Photo> _photos;

    public PhotoList()
    {
        _photos = new List<Photo>
                      {
                          new Photo{ Source = @"D:\AppImage\1.jpg"},
                          new Photo{ Source = @"D:\AppImage\2.jpg"},
                          new Photo{ Source = @"D:\AppImage\3.jpg"},
                          new Photo{ Source = @"D:\AppImage\4.jpg"},
                          new Photo{ Source = @"D:\AppImage\5.jpg"},
                      };
        ((List<Photo>)this.Data).AddRange(_photos);
    }
}
```

And definitely I'm doing something wrong. Because, now i get the **Cannot create an instance of "PhotoList"** error message while instantiating `PhotoList` within the Resource -

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PhotoList x:Key="MyPhotos"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PhotoList` itself either has to be an `IEnumerable` of `Photo` objects, or it needs to provide one, this can be done by inheriting from [`DataSourceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.datasourceprovider.aspx) and exposing the list that way.

---

**Edit:**
Obviously if you just inherit from `List<T>` nothing will display unless you add items, when i said it should be an `IEnumerable` i meant an immediate implementation that actually enumerates strings right away. If you just want to create a list in XAML you may as well use [`x:Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx).

Also here would be an example of using the `DataSourceProvider`:

```
public class PhotoList : DataSourceProvider
{
    protected override void BeginQuery()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures))
                        .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".png")
        OnQueryFinished(files);
    }
}
```

This will populate your list with the paths of PNG-files in the personal "Pictures" folder.

Also you will not get the `DataTemplate`-less appearance of the example if you use a class like `Photo` unless you override `ToString` to return the source URL because by default if there is no `DataTemplate` it will just display the full name of the class.

---

In any case you need `Photo` objects in your collection for the `DataTemplate` to apply properly. Also you usually do not have collections directly in XAML but some data object which is the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of the `Window`/`UserControl`.

Comment: The point of the question is to get the result, as shown in the image, before applying the `DataTemplate` and to get an idea of the `Resource` that make that happen. I'm gonna add an Edit for you to the question.

Comment: LOL. I sure did understand "when i said it should be an IEnumerable", and i didn't mean not to add any item. It's just I thought I'd need some property on that object to store the Photo objects. Never used `DataSourceProvider` before. Thanks a lot for helping on that. I know that "displaying fully qualified class name by default" thing, but are you sure that the result shown on the image cannot be produced anyhow other than overriding the `ToString()`? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @NerotheZero: Of course it can be done without ToString but that would require a DataTemplate with a TextBlock bound to the path, which is beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ph:PhotoList x:Key="MyPhotos"  Path="D:\Visual Studio Projects\WPF APPLICATIONS\ImageViewer\ImageViewer\Images">      
    </ph:PhotoList>    
 </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Ok, so `Path` here is a `string` type property on PhotoList class, right? But how can that give me the `Source` property of `Photo` object to display in the ListBox. I getting an empty Listbox :(